# getting some problem with gridview paging

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages.

In one page I have placed a `GridView`. In the grid I am using two hyperlinks for select and edit. When I click for the edit page I am redirected to another page. When I have finished editing the record it goes back to the first page.

The problem is when I was on the 2nd or 3rd page of the `GridView` and then edited, it went back to first page, not the 2nd or 3rd page I was on.

I want the same page after I go back to the page I left. How can I go about this?

Comment: Please take some time to express your thoughts better.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow ... I hope I helped reformat the question a little better. Please make sure this was what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("einward.aspx");
```

you have to redirect to the page, wtever page u want.

Comment: thanks rucha for u r reply when i click on 2nd page of gridview after that edit link page redirect to another page when i click on save it come back to first page but here i m getting first page index of grid rather then getting second page index of grid it means page get postback how to u mainatin this

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           
        }............u can give that page is nit post back as per my view

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the webpage needs to know what page to send you to. The way I do this is to pass a querystring parameter when I change pages.

So in the URL to the edit page you want to have the URL say (for example) `http://server/edit.aspx?value=number&returnPage=2` and then when you go back to the grid page you'll pass the page value like `http://server/grid.aspx?page=2`

This way you'll always know what page to tell the `GridView` to goto. And it should be pretty easy to add in depending on your level of comfort with the Params object.

Comment: @khan I cannot. I can give you an indication of what to do, which I did, but if this is too complicated for you then I think you should reconsider web-programming. Query string parameter passing is one of the most basic procedures for web programming. Additionally, StackOverflow is not a "plz send me teh codez" website.

Comment: i already using querystring to highlight the gridview row and passing the value from one page to another think is that i m getting little bit confused how to maintain paging while page get postback            protected void Redirectpage(int strCurrID)
    { Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/UI/Master/CurrencyMaster.aspx?id={0}", strCurrID)); }

Comment: You would process it in Page_Load ... I'm really not sure what part about that is hard to process ...

Comment: thanks drachenstem for u r support my problem solved i did through session

Comment: @Khan ~ A) I'm glad you resolved your problem, B) Whatever you did to solve it through session would've worked through GET url parameters, so I hope you take the time one day to learn them, and C) I would love if you pasted the relevant parts of your solution (not the entire pages, just the parts that are relevant to getting the correct page) and marking it as the answer, and D) ...